# CSS Content Image Won't Show up in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

My default browser is Chrome, but I decided to see if my website works well with other browsers. In Chrome, the header has my logo and I used content:url for that so the quality of it is better. However, when I go on my website with Internet Explorer 11, I can still click on the image, but it doesn't show up. My website is http://www.clinkstr.com
Is it just not compatible with IE. If so, is there an alternative for me to maintain a high quality in my logo, even when zoomed in? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post your code here. You're unlikely to get an answer if people have to use an external link.

Comment: Why load such  a large logo image? This can easily be a lot smaller in dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why load such  a large logo image. It looks not good even when downsized.
You can also use background-size to downsize the logo.

```
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo > a {
  background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 40px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 40px;
```

}

IE 8 https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Comment: Thanks, and I will actually change the size of the logo. I didn't know how big I needed it for it to not look blurry when all the way zoomed.

Comment: And also, when I zoom all the way out on my website, the forms start to glitch out in Chrome. And in IE, when I zoom in or out the background-size: cover doesn't work at all.

Comment: Better would be to use a real image tag for your logo. Now you have an empty link which is not ok for SEO and Accessibility. Or at least hidden text alternative.

Comment: How would i use a image tag without the user being able to get the options like image URL or saving the image.

Comment: You cannot prevent the end-user to grab your logo... Even background images you can get with firebug ... You could also put a span inside the a tag and put the name of the website there (brand). You can than hide the text off screen.

Answer (score 2):

The `content` attribute is meant to be used on pseudo elements like `::before` and `::after`. This is documented by the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content), [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and (seen below) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content):

[image]

It appears that Chrome supports this (in a non-standard manner) on regular elements. If you want this to be cross-browser compatible, take the standard approach and use it on a pseudo element.

Always test early in multiple browsers; not doing so may wind up hurting you. In this case, you interpreted Chrome's behavior as being reliable, even though it deviates from standards. Firefox and Internet Explorer both follow the standard, and thus apply `content` to pseudo-elements alone.

Comment: And also, when I zoom all the way out on my website, the forms start to glitch out in Chrome. And in IE, when I zoom in or out the background-size: cover doesn't work at all.

Comment: @CaptainDuude That's a separate question. Please wrap this question up, and then feel free to ask that one.

Comment: A lot of authors treat Chrome as some sort of reference just because of its popularity. It makes me sick that Google abuses this popularity in order to deviate from standards and yet pass off as standards-compliant.